# Make a windowmanager/desktop (Gnome) use only a part of an X11 server's (Xvfb) resolution

Tags: x11, gnome, xvfb

I have the following problem: Let's say I have an X11 server (it is the Xvfb) set to run at a resolution of 1024x768. Now I want to run inside it the Gnome desktop, not at the resolution of 1024x768 but, lets say, 640x480 with the condition that the Gnome desktop is centered inside the X11 space. Anyone knows how to do that? I have tried passing gnome-session the parameter --geometry but it does not like it.
Just In case it matters: The system is a Centos 5.5 with the latest updates installted.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Clearly not a programming question.

Comment: yep, i realize now. sorry for this. can you point me to a place where to ask this question? thanks!

Comment: Looks like XY problem http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Answer (score 1):

Why not just set the Xvfb to the correct size to begin with?

I suppose you could run a nested X server like [Xephyr](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/Xephyr) or [Xnest](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/man/man1/Xnest.1.xhtml) inside the Xvfb, and have it at the right resolution and position, but that's a lot of extra work vs. just running `Xvfb -screen 0 640x480x24`